# How to change a bitmap drawn on a canvas with vue-nativescript on android?

Tags: typescript, nativescript, android-canvas, nativescript-vue

I want to draw a rectangle on a bitmap and change that bitmap later when the user clicks a button. Here my [pastebin example](https://paste.ee/p/Yz764). I was not able to upload a sample PNG and tns-core-modules to Playground, for this reason you cannot execute this unfortunately.

I am using a vue-native app with nativescript (tns --version: 5.4.0) and typescript on an android 8.1 emulator.

To draw shapes I am using a Placeholder component based on the blog post [How to create a canvas in nativescript](https://medium.com/@info_25865/how-to-create-a-canvas-in-nativescript-90c47b067b4b) and a [Playground example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-vue&id=YmSEzF) by Tiago Alves.  The Placeholder creates the view with `@creatingView="createCanvasView"`. In this method I create an `ImageView` and the android native canvas `let canvas = new android.graphics.Canvas(bitmap)`. I can draw a bitmap and a rectangle using `canvas.drawBitmap(picture1)` and `canvas.drawRect(...)`. Finally I draw this view into the component.

```
nativeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
event.view = nativeView;
```

Now my problem starts. I want to replace `picture1` with `picture2` when the user presses a button that calls  `@tap="changePicture1"`.

Ideally I would be able to retrieve the canvas, identify the assets (rectangles, bitmaps...), change the bitmap and redraw. I don't know how to do that.

As a simpler case I try to change the picture of an Image. Here I get a view and set it to the new image - this works:

```
changePicture1() {
let picture1 = < Image > topmost().currentPage.getViewById(
                'myCanvasView');
picture1.imageSource = this.$store.state.image;
}
```

Also via binding I can change an Image:

```
changePicture2() {
this.picUrl =  "~/assets/picture2.png"
}
```

Attempting to do this in a canvas is where I get confused.
Here some attempts to change picUrl and then redraw the canvas.

```
changePicture3() {
this.pic = this.$store.state.projects[0].image;
// Redraw the view to update new bitmap on canvas
let picView = topmost().currentPage;
picView.android.invalidate();
// let nv = <ViewBase> this.$refs.Placeholder; 
// nv.nativeView.invalidate()
// picLane.android.invalidate()
this.picView = this.$store.state.image;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not replace nativeView of PlaceHolder outside `creatingView` event. You should get the existing nativeView from the PlaceHolder then just update the bitmap.

```
// this.$refs.CanvasViewRef returns Vue object
// this.$refs.CanvasViewRef.nativeView returns the actual Placeholder
const nativeView = this.$refs.CanvasViewRef.nativeView.nativeView; 

...
...

nativeView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fast response! That worked perfectly. Saved me several sleepless nights.